# "if'" condition never Go to the Else in android

Tags: android, if-statement, conditional-statements

ive been trying to run this code, but the condition result never going to the else ,even when the value of my slat is 0.0

```
public void keLogin(){
    if(slat.equals("0.0")) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pls wait until we know your location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Intent keLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login_Activity.class);
        keLogin.putExtra("slat", slat);
        keLogin.putExtra("slong", slong);
        startActivity(keLogin);
    }
}
```

Comment: you know truth is true.

Comment: _even when the value of my slat is 0.0_. When value of slat is 0.0, it will only go to if part or did I miss something...:/

Comment: @DroidDev ..you didn't :-p

Comment: you are right why would else be executed "even when the value of my slat is 0.0."

Comment: slat is string, ive changed my 'slat' to another value and the result still never to the else . .

Comment: sorry i got my fault, everything is ok on my code. .  . thankyou

Answer (score 2):

```
public void keLogin(){
if(!slat.equals("0.0")) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pls wait until we know your location",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Intent keLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login_Activity.class);
    keLogin.putExtra("slat", slat);
    keLogin.putExtra("slong", slong);
    startActivity(keLogin);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the `salt` is NOT a String variable: so you should convert it
and If it's a String variable:

1. Maybe your app don't change that variable
2. or that variable didn't achieve to "0.0"

---

- In 1st option you must add some code for changing that value
- In 2nd option you can must change "0.0" to an accessible value

Comment: Do you need more help?

Answer (score -3):

Try using

```
if(slat.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0") { }
```

Might work.